# regex to add `//` before hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I use the below function to wrap/parse links in a string with an `a` tag. 
This supports plain links in a string, but also markdown notation, like `[title](link)`.

But I have a problem: how to fill `//` in the href attribute, when the link doesn't have `//`?

Test data:

```
google.com                     // ok: leave this as is
www.google.com                 // error: need to add `//` in href value
http://google.com              // ok
http://www.google.com          // ok
[google](google.com)           // error: need to add `//` in href value
[google](www.google.com)       // error: need to add `//` in href value
[google](http://google.com)    // error: need to add `//` in href value
```

See [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0p90pyc9/1/)

```js
var markdownParse = (function() {

  return {
    autoLinks: function(text, options) {
      var simpleURLRegex = /\b(((https?|ftp|dict):\/\/|www\.)[^'">\s]+\.[^'">\s]+)(?=\s|$)(?!["<>])/gi;
      text = text.replace(simpleURLRegex, '<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>');
      return text;
    },
    stripLinkDefinitions: function(text) {
      text = text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gi, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
      return text;
    },
  }
})();

$('.convert').on('click', function() {
 var inputVal = $('.input').val();
  
  inputVal = markdownParse.autoLinks(inputVal);
  inputVal = markdownParse.stripLinkDefinitions(inputVal);
  
  $('.output').html(inputVal)
});
```

```css
.convert {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.output {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea class="input"></textarea>

<div class="output"></div>

<div class="convert">convert</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `replace` method with a callback function. That function could then add the `http://` prefix if it is not there yet.

By using a callback you can also treat both cases in one regexp replace call:

```js
var markdownParse = (function() {
  return {
    autoLinks: function(text, options) {
      var simpleURLRegex = 
        (options && options.stripDefinitions ? '\\[(.*?)\\]\\((.*?)\\)|' : '()()')
        + '\\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|dict):\\/\\/|www\\.)[^\'">\\s)]+\\.[^\'">\\s)\\.]+';
      return text.replace(new RegExp(simpleURLRegex, "gi"), function (all, name, url) {
        url = url || all;
        if (url.indexOf('://') === -1) url = 'http://' + url;
        return '<a href="' + url +  '">' + (name || all) + '</a>';
      });
    },
  }
})();


$('.convert').on('click', function() {
  var inputVal = $('.input').val();
  var options = {
    stripDefinitions: $('#markdown').is(':checked')
  }
  inputVal = markdownParse.autoLinks(inputVal, options);
  $('.output').html(inputVal);
  $('.outHTML').text(inputVal);
});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
.output, .outHTML {
  white-space:pre;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="input">You can reach google.com via www.google.com or even
http://google.com and http://www.google.com. Put it like 
[google](google.com) or like [google](www.google.com) or like [google](http://google.com).
</textarea><br>
<button class="convert">Convert</button><input id="markdown" type="checkbox" checked>support markdown
<div class="output"></div>
<div class="outHTML"></div>
```

The options parameter can be used to indicate whether markdown should also be recognised.

Comment: does this regex mix two function? How to separate back to two function?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because I want to let user calling this lib,  option choose to use `[]()` style markdown or just inline link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0p90pyc9/2/  I can't find how to match first function,and after I add callback in second function stripLinkDefinitions, it also fail too, I tried if I only call second it works.

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem with two separate methods is that the first one will also update hyperlink links that are in markdown brackets, and so when the second method would kick in, the damage is already done. I suggest one method, where you pass an option which way you want to replace.